# Find the nearest non zero number in a column of a specific index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,5]})

    A
0   0
1   0
2   15
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   5
```

Now based on the index(lets say 5) I want to determine the nearest non zero number in the column(here index 2 and value 15) and return the hops it takes to get there from given index.
In the given example it would be +3 as it comes from index 2 to index 5 and if the given index is 7 then the answer would be -2 as index is 9 value 5

Comment: How about any thing you have tried so far...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by finding the indexes of all non-zero elements:

```
nonzeros = df[df.A != 0]).index
```

Calculate the distances from your row to all of them:

```
anchor = 5
dists = anchor - nonzeros
```

Find the smallest distance (by the absolute value):

```
nhops = min(dists, key=abs)
```

**Altogether, in one line:**

```
hnops = min((anchor - df[df.A != 0].index), key=abs)
#3
```

The index of the closest non-zero value can be calculated by recombining `nhops` and `anchor`:

```
min_index = anchor - nhops
#2
```

Comment: How can the direction be taken care of in this? like if the required index is above the given then + and if it is below then -

Comment: The number of hops is signed: positive for the values above, negative for the values below.

Comment: Because `abs` is applied temporarily, only for the purpose of sorting.

Answer (score 1):

With a boolean vector of zero/non-zero, you can calculate the distance from a given index to the non-zero values using `subtract()`.  That will give you the "hops", and `idxmin()` can locate the actual value.

```
def get_closest(df, target):
    df["not_zero"] = df.ne(0)
    not_zero = pd.Series(df.index[df.not_zero])
    dist = not_zero.subtract(target).abs()
    minidx = not_zero.loc[dist.idxmin()]
    steps = dist.min() if minidx < target else -dist.min()
    print("Closest steps to non-zero:", steps)
    print("Closest non-zero value:", df.A[minidx])

get_closest(df, 5)
# Closest steps to non-zero: 3
# Closest non-zero value: 15

get_closest(df, 7)
# Closest steps to non-zero: -2
# Closest non-zero value: 5
```

Comment: what if the required index is below the given index? then it should give a negative example

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `nonzero` with `argmin`

```
a=df.A.nonzero()[0]
a[abs(np.argmin(a-5))]
Out[950]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.flatnonzero` to return back the positions of where the array has non zero values.
Subtract the index you are referencing from to get the direction and distance from those positions.

```
d = np.flatnonzero(df.A.values) - 5
i = d[np.abs(d).argmin()] + 5

df.iloc[i]

A    15
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```